# Hong Kong ID Card

Tags: hong-kong

Can someone steer me in the right direction.

I was born in UK to Chinese parents (1984), China and Hong Kong born (grandparents and ancestry can be traced back). I have only been back once for a family visit.

My father had a HK ID card but no HK passport. He had a UK passport and lived in UK since approx 1980.

Both my parents have now passed, mother in 2000 and father this year.

Is there anything I can do about getting a HK ID card by ancestry? I have my father's birth certificate but not mother's - I could probably locate it somehow.

Comment: why did you delete your [previous similar question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21935/hong-kong-id-passport-eligibility-for-uk-born-chinese)?

Comment: I hadnt realised i posted similar, in any case my situation is different now due to my father passing so the ask is different

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.*

You might need to start finding out if you have the [right of abode (RoA)](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/right-of-abode-in-hksar.html) in Hong Kong. This would also be related to whether you are already eligible for [Chinese nationality](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/chinese_nationality.html) by descent, which depends on your parents' nationality and residency at the time you were born. To answer these questions, you might then want to recover all identity documents of your parents as much as possible to find out when and how your parents acquired their British and Chinese citizenship/nationality.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your parents' citizenship at the time of your birth. If your parents, or at least one of them, were still Chinese citizens when you were born, you are eligible to Chinese citizenship. But would lose your UK citizenship, maybe not what you want.

For the right of the abode, it is the same, but the parent has to be (a) Chinese at the time of your birth, and (b) have the right of abode. So if your father (who was the one with right of abode) was still a Chinese citizen, all good. [You qualify](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/roa/eligible.html). If not, you're not eligible. A British citizen with HKPR cannot pass HKPR to overseas-born children.

Comment: "you are eligible to Chinese citizenship. But would lose your UK citizenship" If the conditions in Article 5 of the PRC nationality law were met, the child is automatically and involuntarily a Chinese citizen at birth, not "eligible to". There is no reason under PRC or British law why they would lose British citizenship.

Comment: Article 9: "Any Chinese national who has settled abroad and who has been naturalised as a foreign national or has acquired foreign nationality of his own free will shall automatically lose Chinese nationality."

Comment: Article 9 deals with people who voluntarily acquire a foreign nationality after birth, so it is irrelevant to someone who automatically has multiple nationalities at birth. (It wouldn't make sense anyway to say one both acquires and loses Chinese nationality at the moment of birth.)